# How can I obtain the Smith normal form of large matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, smith-normal-form

Sorry that I could not include the matrix to the title, it goes over the limit of character number.
The given matrix is \begin{bmatrix}x-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&x-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&x-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{3}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&x-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}
I tried to find appropriate pivot, and I got
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&2x&x^2-x-2\\0&0&-4x^2+2x&x^2-1\end{bmatrix}
but now stuck here. I think I have done something wrong. My guess is that by the properties of normal form, it should be \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&x^4-2x^3+2x^2-1\end{bmatrix} Can you show several steps to get the answer?

Comment: Do you actually  need the steps to achieve the transformation, or are you happy with a proof that the  matrix you (rightly) say is the normal form is the normal form?

Comment: I need the steps, since I already proved it is the normal form. The actual problem is that even I know the latter one is the real normal form, but I cannot achieve it by applying algorithm.

Comment: The Smith Normal Form Algorithm that I know is a genuine algorithm: at each stage there is exactly one thing that we must do next. So I see no problem except the tedious business of actually doing it. ;-)  But I will put a suggestion in the answers.

Comment: No need to be sorry. One actually should not include the matrix in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that
$$
1=\frac{x-1}{4}\cdot 2x -\frac{1}{2}\cdot (x^2-x-2)
$$
so that we should replace $C_3$ by $\frac{x-1}{4}\cdot C_3 -\frac{1}{2}\cdot C_4$. [This is possible by a sequence of steps dictated by the extended Euclidean Algorithm that calculates the HCF.]

We then use the $1$ in the $(3,3)$ to clear the off diagonal entries. As all this preserves the determinant we'll get the correct entry in the $(4,4)$ place.

Comment: I think it cannot obtain the correct (4,4) entry: I got the equation of 5th degree. Can you check it?

Comment: I found some mistakes in my calculation. Actually, the second matrix in my question is wrong. But thank you for giving me a nice motivation!